# Number of combinations between two people

Tags: combinatorics

I trying to find an algorithm that will give me the total number of unique combinations of a sequence of numbers between two people.

If I have the following numbers: 1,3,3,3.

Then this can be split in 2 ways between two people:

Person 1    Person 2

1,3.........3 3

3,3.........1 3

There are 2 combinations here.

Likewise, if I have the following numbers: 1,1,2,2.

Then this can be split in the following ways:

Person 1    Person 2

1,1.........2,2

1,2.........1,2

2,2.........1,1

There are 3 combinations here.

I tried using the following formula

(n+r-1)! / r!(n-1)!

where n is the number of distinct numbers and r is the size of the combinations.

That didn't give me the right answer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Please consider making your question clearer or else it may be removed?

Comment: Do you need to split evenly the resources between people ? Like couldn't you give '1' to Person $1$ and '333' to Person $2$ ?

Comment: Sorry, to make it clearer, the numbers have to be split in equal number between the two people. In both cases since there are four numbers, each person gets two each.

Comment: Are you considering all sequences with 4 numbers or all sequences with even numbers?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please edit your question to address the questions that have been raised in the comments.

Comment: I'm considering all sequences with even numbers.